# doing animation in one laptop and render it in another is this possible?

Tags: rendering, animation

I had made a big animation in my laptop but now the problem is the process of rendering, I can't render in my laptop because it is 2GB RAM. So is it possible to copy it in another laptop and render it?

Comment: of course, if you use textures make sure you also copy them in a folder, or even simpler: pack them all into your blend file with File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend

Comment: Thank you so much it helped me lot

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you use image textures make sure to also copy them in a folder, or even simpler: pack them all into your blend file with *File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend*.